# Objective-C custom property getter infinite recursion

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have an Objective-C class that implements a node for a data tree. Its properties are read-only to the public while a private extension of the class (not shown here) implements the properties' setters so a manager class can create the tree.

```
// Interface
@interface DataSet : NSObject {
    NSString        *name;
    NSString        *data;
@private
    DataSet         *parent;
    NSMutableArray  *children;
}
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSString *data;
```

I want to implement a custom getter for one of the properties that, if the property is nil, will walk up the tree until it finds an ancestor node that has a non-nil value for that property.

My problem is implementing the getter without causing an infinite recursion of the getter calling itself.

```
// Implementation
@interface DataSet ()
@property (nonatomic, retain) DataSet           *parent;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray    *children;
@end

@implementation DataSet

@synthesize name;
// do not @synthesize data
@synthesize parent, children;

// custom getter walks up tree to find first non-nil 'data' property
- (NSString*) data {
    NSString *result = nil;
    DataSet *set = self;
    while (set != nil && result == nil) {
        result = [set data];    // <=== INFINITE RECURSION HERE
        set = set.parent;
    }
    return result;
}
```

I've searched through this and other forums but haven't found any examples of what I'm trying to do here. Anyone have any suggestions?

Also, should the last line in the getter be

```
return [result copy];
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmmm, I think you want something like this:

```
-(NSString *) data {
    // Determine result from current instance data.
    NSString *result = ....; 

    // If nothing, ask parent instance of this instance.
    if (result == nil) {
        result = [parent data];
    }

    // Might still be nil if parent returns nothing.
    return result;
}
```

Hmmm, actually seeing as you have a `data` variable containing some textural data, it could be done like this:

```
-(NSString *) data {
    // If data is nil, ask parent instance for a value, otherwise return a copy.
    return data == nil ? [parent data] : [data copy];
}
```

So each instance of DataSet doesn't need to have a loop. All they do is check with their immediate parent. This way if you have a data graph of A -> B -> C -> D and execute `[D data];` the D will check itself and then as C, which will check itself and then as B, which will check itself and then ask A. You will get back the first successful non-nil value for result.

Comment: This will work, but it will be less efficient than a single `while` loop—sending Objective-C messages have a bit more overhead than a regular C function call (what with the dynamic dispatch and all).

Comment: I'm coming from Java to Objective C so whilst the looping solution might be faster, I'd personally go the Objective C one because I find it easier to understand at a glance. Unless of course, there was a real speed problem stemming from lots of calls. :-)

Comment: The other advantage of this approach is that it supports including subclasses of `DataSet` in the tree -- a subclass might override the `-data` getter, but if you directly access the iVar, you defeat that. This solution is shorter, clearer, and more "Objective-". Unless/until you know (have *measured*, not guessed) that "less efficient" is leading to a performance problem I'd avoid the "`while` loop grubbing around in other objects' iVars" model.

Comment: @adam premature optimization is the curse that leads to fragile codebases... unless the hierarchy is ridiculously deep, the message send overhead in that code is exceedingly unlikely to ever matter.

Comment: Ah, but that `NSString *result = ....;` is just the mystery I was trying to solve. If I try your approach while using the ivar directly (`NSString *result = self->data;`), I crash in dealloc because I skip over the nil 'data's and release some non-nil 'data's twice. EXC_BAD_ACCESS!

Comment: See my modified (really short) option. It can be confusing because I'm both access the current instance's data variable and refering the the parent instance's data method, but it should work just fine. (I don't have a mac in front of me to test to be 100% sure :-)

Answer (score 3):

Just access the ivar directly:

```
// custom getter walks up tree to find first non-nil 'data' property
- (NSString*) data {
    NSString *result = nil;
    DataSet *set = self;
    while (set != nil && result == nil) {
        result = set->data;
        set = set->parent;
    }
    return [result copy];
}
```

This avoids calling the property accessor and therefore avoids recursion.

And yes, the last line should be `return [result copy];`, because you declared your property as having the `copy` property.  If you hadn't declared it with the `copy` property, then you would not return a copy.

Comment: Do not access ivars directly;  this breaks encapsulation and makes subclassing difficult (a subclass can no longer override behavior).

Comment: Thank you, Adam! I knew there had to be a way to access the property's value directly, but couldn't seem to find the right combination to make it work. This does the job!

Comment: No, really, it doesn't.  You are breaking encapsulation.  The underlying problem is that your algorithm was wrong for the situation.  Use Derek's solution (or one like it).   Using `->` to access the contents of an object is **entirely against the fundamental patterns of the language**.

Comment: Then I still don't have a solution to my problem. As my response to Derek notes, `NSString result = ...;` is missing exactly the piece of the puzzle I am seeking: how to access a property directly inside its custom getter without infinite recursion.

Comment: @SteveCaine - I put `NSString *result = ...;` because I could not see anything in your code example that set it to a value. It first sets it to nil, then sets it to whatever the parent instance returns. As the parent instance is an instance of the same class, it would execute the same code - set to nil, then set to parent. So I said `...` to represent whatever code you have in the DataSet class that actually sets `result` to a value other than nil or the result of `[parent data];`. Sorry if I confused people.

Comment: @Derek - The actual project reads an XML file and creates a DataSet for each XML element, setting the object's properties from the element's XML attributes. Some attributes will be missing from some elements, in which case the custom getter is supposed look for the first non-nil value for that property/attribute in the chain of the object's ancestors. So by the time we reach the custom getter, the object either does/doesn't have a value for that property. I need `NSString *result` to get the current value of that property inside the getter WITHOUT calling itself recursively.

Comment: @SteveCaine - Just realised you said "Reads an XML file". I have to ask - why not use the NSXmlParser? it's designed to do just that and save you all the pain. I've got a project on GitHub called dXml which I built to access SOAP based web services and in it's test code I read XML from strings.

Comment: @Derek - I am using NSXMLParser to parse the XML file, this class just holds the data I get from the parser's callbacks, one object for each XML element, linked together in a parent<-object->children data tree.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

I can call the custom getter recursively on an object's *parent* (but not on the object itself). That's not the problem.

What's key is NOT to use the custom getter in dealloc when I'm releasing the object, or else some 'data' objects will be returned (and thus released) multiple times.

```
// custom getter - if data is nil on this object, 
// find the first non-nil value in its list of ancestors
- (NSString*) data {
    NSString *result = data;
    if (result == nil && parent != nil)
        result = [parent data];
    return result;
}

- (void) dealloc {
    NSInteger count = [children count];
    for (NSInteger index = count - 1; index >= 0; --index) {
        DataSet *child = [children objectAtIndex:index];
        [children removeLastObject];
        [child release];
    }
    [children release];

    // DON'T call custom getter if data is nil
    // or we'll get one of its ancestors' data object, release it,
    // then later release it again when releasing the ancestor
    if (data != nil)
        [self.data release];

    [self.name release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Several things about this code. 1. You don't need to write code to release object held in a NSArray. It will do it automatically. so that gets ride of the loop. 2. You don't need to do `if (data ...{...}` like that. Because Objective C allows sending messages to nil and setters correclty handle releases of old values, you can simple replace it with `self.data = nil;` So to cut a long story short :-) You can do: `-(void) dealloc { self.children = nil; self.name = nil; self.data = nil; [super dealloc]; }`

Comment: Ah, a light dawns. I come from a C++ background, so I tend to be obsessive about memory management. You're saying my code goes to a lot of trouble to do what the language would do for me. After running Instruments and fixing some alloc/release issues, I find all my objects are being released when I use your code. Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you have above, it's just that in a lot of cases, the SDK has the code built in. So it's always worth checking the doco as they usually tell you when retains/releases are done.